# Get specific files from a folder and save them in a list

Tags: python, file, filesystems

I have different files in a folder and I would like to sort them and save the sorted ones in a list. My goal is to only save the files from the year 2021 with the ending '.txt'

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Python-Files\Test_OS")
list = []

for file in os.listdir("."):
    date, fileName = file.split("-")
    name, fileFormat = fileName.split(".")
    i = 1
    print(date, name, fileFormat)
    if fileFormat == "txt" and date == f"0{i}.2021":
        list.append(file)
        i = i + 1
        print(f"0{i}.2021")
```

My Folder looks like this:

```
'01.2020-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '01.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '02.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '02.2021-Monatsabshluss.bmp',
 '03.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '04.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '05.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '06.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt'
```

If I execute my code the list only contains '01.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the loop is off - you only increment `i` once after comparing against `date`. You'd need to keep increasing `i` in an inner loop to match `02`, `03`, etc.

However, it would be much simpler to use pathname globbing:

```
from glob import glob
filelist = glob("0?.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt")
```

which will give you:

```
['01.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '02.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '03.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '04.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '05.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt',
 '06.2021-Monatsabschluss.txt']
```

The `?` will match any character, so if you want to restrict it to `1-9` (to specify a month), you could use the pattern `"0[1-9].2021-Monatsabschluss.txt"`.

(also, it's best to not name a list `list` because `list` is the name of the built-in `list` type).